# How can I add home folder (`~`) into lsp-workspace-blacklist

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I want to add user's home folder (`~`) into the `lsp-workspace-blacklist` in the init file. Is it possible to achieve this in the init file?

I have tried `(lsp-project-blacklist (quote ("~")))` but seems like `~` is not detected:

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/605) seems to indicate that `lsp-project-blacklist` is obsolete. You might want to check the issue out and/or upgrade your `lsp-mode` before you do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is a shell-ism. Try `(setq lsp-project-blacklist (list (expand-file-name "~")))`[1].

`C-h f expand-file-name` says:

```
Convert filename NAME to absolute, and canonicalize it.
Second arg DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is directory to start with if NAME is relative
(does not start with slash or tilde); both the directory name and
a directory’s file name are accepted.  If DEFAULT-DIRECTORY is nil or
missing, the current buffer’s value of ‘default-directory’ is used.
NAME should be a string that is a valid file name for the underlying
filesystem.

File name components that are ‘.’ are removed, and so are file name
components followed by ‘..’, along with the ‘..’ itself; note that
these simplifications are done without checking the resulting file
names in the file system.

Multiple consecutive slashes are collapsed into a single slash, except
at the beginning of the file name when they are significant (e.g., UNC
file names on MS-Windows.)

An initial "~" in NAME expands to your home directory.

An initial "~USER" in NAME expands to USER’s home directory.  If
USER doesn’t exist, "~USER" is not expanded.

To do other file name substitutions, see ‘substitute-in-file-name’.
```

It's a handy function to keep in mind.

---

[1] I assume that `lsp-project-blacklist` is a list of paths, but I don't actually know what its type is, so this is just a suggestion to try.

Comment: So should I do: `(lsp-project-blacklist (quote ((expand-file-name "~"))))` ?

Comment: No, `quote` would inhibit evaluation: you *want* to evaluate the `expand-filename`, so you can use the backquote mechanism or construct the list expicitly. I've added a suggestion using the explicit construction, but heed the caveat in the footnote.

Comment: `)` is missing at the end of `(setq lsp-project-blacklist ..` line

Comment: Fixed - thanks!

Comment: I have tested and it works but it blacklists all the subfolders as well: `File '/home/alper/work/Driver.py' is in blacklisted directory '/home/alper/'` ; do you think could we force to consider only `/home/user` but exclude its subfolders from the blacklist

Comment: I don't know: that's a question about how `lsp-project-blacklist` works and that's something I know nothing about. You should probably ask a specific question about that.

Comment: I will do that , thanks again