# How can I blacklist a folder but not its subfolders in lsp?

Tags: lsp

I am using [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) and want to blacklist specific folders, such as `~`, but not their subfolders. The way I do it, from following answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73411/18414:

> `(setq lsp-project-blacklist (list (expand-file-name "~")))`

When I open a file inside `/home/alper/work`, subfolder inside `~`, now I am getting follow message:

```
File '/home/alper/work/Driver.py' is in blacklisted directory '/home/alper/'
```

Here is it possible to blacklist only home folder (`~`) but not its subfolders?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/605) seems to indicate that `lsp-project-blacklist` is obsolete. You might want to check the issue out and/or upgrade your `lsp-mode` before you do anything else.

Comment: Do think: `(setq lsp-workspace-folders-remove (list (expand-file-name "~")))` would work?

Comment: Try it and see - as I said in the other question, I know very little about `lsp`.